# Error Generating ER models with gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Each time i try generating an ER diagram in my rails application using **"railsroady"** i keep getting this error.

```
error
$ rake diagram:all
Generating C:/User\ 
pc_user/Documents/department/doc/models_complete.svg
railroady -lamM | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g" | dot 
-Tsvg > C:/Users/Wokoro\ Samuel/Documents/department/doc/models_complete.svg
The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect.
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (255): [railroady -lamM | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]
{1...]
```

Comment: from error message, it showing that the path has problem, since you using windows you should try to use -r option from https://github.com/preston/railroady

Comment: Thanks for your reply I would do that and see if it would work. @widjajayd